# How to use IUPnPRegistrar::GetUniqueDeviceName?

Tags: windows, delphi, upnp

I am testing on uPNP API. There is a method: IUPnPRegistrar::GetUniqueDeviceName.  How may I use that to get unique device name.  Here is the method's parameters:

```
HRESULT GetUniqueDeviceName(
  [in]   BSTR bstrDeviceIdentifier,
  [in]   BSTR bstrTemplateUDN,
  [out]  BSTR *pbstrUDN
);
```

In my host, there is a media player device:

```
IsRootDevice=-1
UniqueDeviceName=uuid:a0a07e13-cc50-4db0-97b3-2a4b93ef0736
FriendlyName=VISITOR
type_=urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaRenderer:1
PresentationURL=
ManufacturerName=Microsoft Corporation
ManufacturerURL=http://www.microsoft.com/
ModelName=Windows Media Player
ModelNumber=12
Description=Windows Media Player Renderer
ModelURL=http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=105927
UPC=
SerialNumber={DCD14EBE-CEAE-421F-87DE-2C10780E99E2}
Service=urn:upnp-org:serviceId:RenderingControl
ServiceTypeIdentifier=urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1
```

I presume the UniqueDeviceName of my device is "uuid:a0a07e13-cc50-4db0-97b3-2a4b93ef0736".  What value should I pass to first and second parameters in order to retrieve the third value in the method?

Answer (score 0):

**GetUniqueDeviceName** is just a wrapper around Win32 C API call **[UpnpGetUDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa451146.aspx)**. That one explicitly says that *pszTemplateUDN* (that is *bstrTemplateUDN* in **GetUniqueDeviceName**) may be NULL, in which case you get back UDN of the root device. I for one do not understand what Microsoft means by "device description template". Better said, i know what device description template in UPnP means, but that doesn't hold any specific UDNs. It's a template, right? So perhaps just a confusing name for the *[UPNPDEVICEINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa451144.aspx)* struct which you are expected to hold across the system reboot. Which is required by UPnP but Windows upnphost doesn't do for you.

So to answer you question:

- *strDeviceIdentifier* you should have get from the RegisterDevice
- *bstrTemplateUDN* you are safe with NULL as long as you have no embedded devices in your testing device (i still have to see such device)
- *pbstrUDN* is your returned UDN for the specified device

Disclaimer: i don't know upnphost neither iupnpregistrar, i just happen to have some background in UPnP and Win32 API so know where to dig for informations.